# architecture binary-amd64 not recognized in ubuntu mirror

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-s3, ubuntu-16.04, aptly

I am using preseed to install ubuntu 16.04 and I have a setup that works fine with the regular ubuntu mirror if I specify

```
d-i mirror/http/hostname string archive.ubuntu.com
d-i mirror/http/directory string /ubuntu
```

I have now been given a specific mirror to use in place of archive.ubuntu.com so I have changed those lines to

```
d-i mirror/http/hostname string <comapany-domain>.s3-website-us-west-1.amazonaws.com
d-i mirror/http/directory string /
```

I'm now seeing an error that says "Architecture not supported, The specified Ubuntu archive mirror does not seen to support your architecture. Please try a different mirror."

The mirror is hosted on s3 and the directory structure looks like

```
dists/
  xenial/
    main/
      binary-amd64/
        Packages.bz2
        Packages.gz
        Release
      contents-amd64.gz
    InRelease
    Release
    Release.gpg
pool/
  main/
    a/
    b/
    c/
    .....
```

Note that there is no /ubuntu/ folder which is why I specify "directory string /"  I'm pretty sure this is correct because with anything else in that line I see a different error "bad archive mirror"

I'm comparing with http://www.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ and there are some extra directories such as indices, project, ubuntu.

Why does it not recognize dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64 as the correct architecture?

I have also confirmed that the same error appears when I try a manual install without the preseed configuration.

Comment: You probably want to talk to whoever directed you to use a broken mirror.

Comment: thanks,  I already did that and I was told to figure out why it was broken.  Any ideas?

Comment: Because whoever set it up did so incorrectly.